# Qt - loss of behavior when reimplementing QWidget::event()

Tags: c++, qt, events

Problem:

I derived an class from `QToolButton` and reimplemented the event function so I could have access to the QHover events - which I am able to do. However the buttons have lost some of their other functionality, as if only the events I am catching are being processed. For instance, the buttons don't visually looked pressed (when you click on them), the `QButtonGroup` they're in doesn't seem to have any information about them (e.g., `isChecked()` is always false and no signals seem to fire). In the code below you can see that I started going down the road of keeping track of the button's state myself, but that bothers me because I know that I'm missing something very simple - yet very important - that is jamming things up.

Things I've tried:

- I tried adding `event->ignore()` and `return false` in the case blocks, but the problem remains the same (ignore, accept, false, true, none of it effects any difference)
- I end the event function with `return QWidget::event(event)`, because as best as I can find in the docs that's how you pass on the event, but it evidently doesn't do what I think it's supposed to do
- (added after reading melak47's comment): I have also ping-ponged back and forth between `QWidget::event` and `this->QToolButton::event` to no avail. The latter implementation did seem like the more correct way to do things, but since it didn't change anything I went with what I saw in other code.
- If I comment out the entire event function the buttons get functionality back (but of course, then I can't see the hover event). I could make an `eventFilter` to peek at the enter and leave events, but I was trying to avoid having the parent intercept the child's events if the child could do it on it's own.

```
class NavButton : public QToolButton()
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        NavButton(int buttonid, bool buttonState = 0, QWidget *parent = 0)
            : QToolButton( parent ), id(buttonid), state(buttonState)
        {
            //setMouseTracking(true);
            setAttribute(Qt::WA_Hover);
        }

       ~NavButton(){}
        void setActiveIcon(QIcon active)      {aIcon = active;}
        void setInActiveIcon(QIcon inactive)  {iIcon = inactive;}
        void setHoverIcon(QIcon hover)        {hIcon = hover;}
        int  getId()                          {return  id;}
        bool getState()                       {return  state;}
        void setId(int buttonId)              {id    = buttonId;}
        void setState(int buttonState)
             {
                 state = buttonState;
                 QIcon icon = (state) ? aIcon : iIcon;
                 setIcon(icon);
             }

    protected:
        void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *)   {/*repaint();*/}
        void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *) {emit stateChanged(id, state);}
        void hoverEnter(QHoverEvent *)        {setIcon(QIcon(hIcon));}
        void hoverLeave(QHoverEvent *)
             {
                 QIcon icon = (state) ? aIcon : iIcon;
                 setIcon(icon);
             }

        bool event(QEvent *event)
             {
                 switch(event->type())
                 {
                     case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:
                         mousePressEvent((QMouseEvent*)(event));
                         break;
                     case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
                         mouseReleaseEvent((QMouseEvent*)(event));
                         //event->ignore();                         // Makes no difference
                         //return false;                            // Makes no difference
                         break;
                     case QEvent::HoverEnter:
                         hoverEnter((QHoverEvent*)(event));
                         break;
                     case QEvent::HoverLeave:
                         hoverLeave((QHoverEvent*)(event));
                         break;
                     default:
                         break;
                 }

                 return QWidget::event(event);
             }

    signals:
        void stateChanged(int id, bool state);

    private:
        int   id;
        bool  state;
        QIcon aIcon;
        QIcon iIcon;
        QIcon hIcon;
};
```

The docs and books I've been reading make this sound so simple, plus when I look online no one is having this problem; which makes me think it probably is that easy but I'm just missing some elementary concept.

Any insight is much appreciated

Comment: You're explicitly calling `QWidget::event`, I  *think* you need to call `QToolButton`'s `event` member, if you want to keep its behavior.

Comment: I thought that as well (and I've tried it too), but since that didn't work either, I stuck with what I saw in various code examples.

Comment: @Wolf That's wrong. You need to fix that *and* fix whatever else is broken :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you call your reimplement the `mousePressEvent` and `mouseReleaseEvent` functions in your event-function? I think thats where your problem is! Those are virtual functions, and thus `QToolButton::event` will internally call your implementation of those, instead of calling the original ones!

The following code should do the right thing - by overriding the functions correctly:

```
class NavButton : public QToolButton()
{
        //...
    protected:
        void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
            /*repaint();*/
            QToolButton::mousePressEvent(ev);
        }
        void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *ev) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
            emit stateChanged(id, state);
            QToolButton::mouseReleaseEvent(ev);
        }
        void hoverEnter(QHoverEvent *) {
            setIcon(QIcon(hIcon));
        }
        void hoverLeave(QHoverEvent *) {
            QIcon icon = (state) ? aIcon : iIcon;
            setIcon(icon);
        }

        bool event(QEvent *event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
            switch(event->type()) {
            case QEvent::HoverEnter:
                hoverEnter((QHoverEvent*)(event));
                break;
            case QEvent::HoverLeave:
                hoverLeave((QHoverEvent*)(event));
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

            return QToolButton::event(event);
        }

    //...
};
```

All event handler that have been overriden do now call the handler of the base class. And in your event handler you only need to call the specific handlers that you have created on your own! (The `Q_DECL_OVERRIDE`-macro indicates that you are overriding a function).

Comment: That makes sense, except for the part where the OP says that it's working when he's commenting out the event function.

Comment: Felix, thank you so much. After you pointed it out I could see exactly how I was subverting the event system.

Comment: @Ilya: My implementation of `event()` was actually tying up the other event handlers (so commenting `event()` freed them).

Note to others: 1 minor change to the code suggested by Felix is that the parameter for the two mouse event handlers needs to be changed from `QMouseEvent` (I did that) to `QEvent` (what it's supposed to be)

Comment: @Wolf "tying up the other event handlers" => what's that ? Can you point me on some reference to explain this ? I don't quite get it.

Comment: The system couldn't process the mouse press/release events properly because (#1) `My::event` handler was hijacking them first and redirecting them to `My::mousePressEvent` (this prevented the system from ever being able to directly call the real `mousePressEvent` handler), and (#2) my handlers weren't reposting the event to their respective base handlers (e.g., `My::mousePressEvent` must call `QToolButton::mousePressEvent` for event processing to continue - it didn't. While #2 is certainly the root problem, #1 is still bad because it makes the code convoluted and subverts the event flow model.